# How do I convert this date in to a valid date object?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert string dates like `2020-01-14T17:01:48.757Z` and `2020-01-14T17:01:50.760Z` in to C# DateTime. Looks like my parsing is failing somewhere.

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2020-01-14T17:01:48.757Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DateTime;
```

Whats wrong with above code ? It fails with

> String '2020-01-14T17:01:50.760Z' was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.

When I parse same date online https://nsdateformatter.com/ It has no issues.

I even tried using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` but it also gives above error.

Comment: First you are missing a Dot between second and fraction of second. secondo `zzz` is not what you think https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier, you need fff https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#fffSpecifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this date format:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2020-01-14T17:01:48.757Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DateTime;
```

`2020-01-14T17:01:48.757Z`

`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ`

As You see format corresponds to Your provided date string.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forget to use *proper* format specifier for your milliseconds part and dot (`.`) between your seconds and milliseconds part.

[The `"fff"` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#fffSpecifier)

> The "fff" custom format specifier represents the **three most
>   significant digits of the seconds fraction**; that is, it represents the
>   milliseconds in a date and time value.

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2020-01-14T17:01:48.757Z", 
                          "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffZ",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```